# Finding if roots is integer

Tags: roots

How to solve this: Is $(1782^{12}+1841^{12})^{1/12}$ an integer?
Should I reexpress $1841$ in terms of $1782$, as such:
$1782 = x$, and $1841 = x+59$? I can't make any progress. Please help.

Comment: No! It can not be integer. We know this at least 300 years.

Comment: Please explain. I have not descended from prehistoric times.

Comment: Prove that the equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no natural solutions.

Comment: Fermat proved that no fourth power can be written as the sum of two fourth powers. If your number was an integer $m$, then $(1782^3)^4+(1841^3)^4=(m^3)^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Fermat's last theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYifnA2r7WAhVR-GMKHZgsAC4QFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFermat%2527s_Last_Theorem&usg=AFQjCNFR5lD7yMD3-HPeKqDwvzYa_9zx5g), there are no solutions for
$$c^n = a^n + b^n$$
when a, b, and c are integers and n is an integer greater than 2. If $$\sqrt[12]{(1782^{12}+1841^{12})} = c$$ for some integer c, that would imply that $$1782^{12}+1841^{12} = c^{12}$$ which we know is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Fermat's Last Theorem works works, but so do more elementary approaches.

We have $1782^{12}=(1782^3)^4$ which by Fermat's Little Theorem is $\equiv 1 \bmod 5$.  Likewise for $1241^{12}$. 
 Then a proposed integer $c$ such that $c^{12}=1782^{12}+1241^{12}$ would imply that $c^{12}=(c^3)^4\equiv 2 \bmod 5$, which is contradicted by Fermat's Little Theorem.